# GitLab set up to send invite Email to new members

Tags: puppet, devops, gitlab-omnibus

I'm new to setting up Gitlab.

I have used the [VSHN](https://github.com/vshn/puppet-gitlab) puppet module to install Gitlab in AWS.

The Gitlab server is running fine but the email invite is not working for anyone.

I have used the following configuration in site.pp file.

```
node 'client-ip-address' {

  class { 'gitlab':
    external_url => 'http://client-ip-address',
  }

}
```

Could anyone please tell me what configuration is required to set up email notification?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your method of email, it will be configured with the gitlab rails option configuration documented here: https://github.com/vshn/puppet-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#usage

Documentation on examples for various email providers here: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#example-configuration

For example, the most basic one:

```
class { 'gitlab':
  external_url => 'http://gitlab.mydomain.tld',
  gitlab_rails => {
    'smtp_enable' => true,
  },
}
```

For gmail:

```
class { 'gitlab':
   external_url => 'http://gitlab.mydomain.tld',
   gitlab_rails => {
    'smtp_address' => "smtp.gmail.com"
    'smtp_port' => 587
    'smtp_user_name' => "my.email@gmail.com"
    'smtp_password' => "my-gmail-password"
    'smtp_domain' => "smtp.gmail.com"
    'smtp_authentication' => "login"
    'smtp_enable_starttls_auto' => true
    'smtp_tls' => false
    'smtp_openssl_verify_mode' => 'peer'
},
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this today :)

Comment: Hi Peter,

I have used the above approach. But I want to use a sendmail on Ubuntu.
I have installed sendmail and it is working fine but it is not working with GITLAB.